# PHP and MySQL Radio Button Name = PHP ECHO

Tags: php, mysql

How can I get the clicked button value when its name is echoed by PHP?

Here's my code:

```
<form>

    <input type='radio' name=<?php echo $i; ?> id='choice1' value=<?php echo $row['choices_a']; ?> checked/>
    <?php echo '' .$row['choices_a']. '' ?> 

    <input type='radio' name=<?php echo $i; ?> id='choice2' value=<?php echo $row['choices_b']; ?> />
    <?php echo ''.$row['choices_b'].''?>

    <input type='radio' name=<?php echo $i; ?> id='choice3' value=<?php echo $row['choices_c']; ?> />
    <?php echo ''.$row['choices_c'].''?> <br />

</form>


<?php 
}   echo $total;
?>
```

Comment: I mean how can I get the value from $POST['']?

Comment: you need valid html first

Comment: <input type='radio' name=<?php echo $i; ?> id='choice1' value=<?php echo $row['choices_a']; ?> checked/>
    <?php echo '' .$row['choices_a']. '' ?> 

    <input type='radio' name=<?php echo $i; ?> id='choice2' value=<?php echo $row['choices_b']; ?> />
    <?php echo ''.$row['choices_b'].''?>

    <input type='radio' name=<?php echo $i; ?> id='choice3' value=<?php echo $row['choices_c']; ?> />
    <?php echo ''.$row['choices_c'].''?> <br />

Comment: This is a part of my HTML code

Comment: i get the value of questions from my database

Comment: not valid HTML , missing quotes

Comment: anyway, it is working on my page.

Comment: `<form>` won't send a `POST` request.

Answer (score 0):

You can get value of that radio button is just simply like other inputs

```
$_POST['input_name']
```

And in your case if `i = input_value`,

```
$total = $_POST['input_value'];
echo $total;
```

You can Also check if that is clicked or isset

```
if(isset($_POST['input_value'])){
    $total = $_POST['input_value'];
    echo $total;
}
```

Hope it clears.

Comment: <?php $i = 0;
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
 {
  $i++; //loop for number of data in database

?>

<div class="section">
<span name="questions"><?php echo '<p><b>' .$i.". ".$row['questions'].'</b></p>'?></span> 
</div>

I have this loop above

Comment: Your codes has lots of errors and how you give name any input as i or number. Don't you know that variables name can't be number? Cause you want to take that value by $_POST['name_of_input']. This can't be $_POST['1'].. Please clear your question first. Or edit your question with the given for loop, how you exactly want to show the data